# How to configure Fluent NHibernate explicit left/inner join for an association&

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

First, some code to explain my config:

```
public class OrdersSessionFactoryCreator
    : ISessionFactoryCreator
{
    public NHibernate.ISessionFactory Create()
    {
        var ret =
            Fluently
                .Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
                    .MsSql2008
                    .DoNot.UseOuterJoin()
                    .UseReflectionOptimizer()
                    .ShowSql()
                    .FormatSql()
                    .ConnectionString(ex =>
                        ex.FromConnectionStringWithKey("OrdersSqlServer")))
                .Mappings(
                    x =>
                        x.AutoMappings.Add(
                            AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Order>(new AutoConfig()).UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<Order>()
                                .Conventions.Add<DefaultStringLengthConvention>()
                                .Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.None())))
                .ExposeConfiguration(config => new SchemaExport(config).Create(true, true))
                .BuildSessionFactory();

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Now, the domain model:

```
public class Order : EntityBase
{
    public Order(Guid id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }

    protected Order()
    {
    }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : EntityBase
{
    public Customer(Guid id)
        : base(id)
    {
    }
    protected Customer()
    {
    }

    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Order>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Order> mapping)
    {
        //mapping.HasOne(c => c.Customer).Not.LazyLoad().Cascade.All();
        mapping.References(c => c.Customer).Not.Nullable();
    }
}

public class CustomerMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Customer>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Customer> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(o => o.Orders).Cascade.All().Fetch.Join();
    }
}
```

Now, if I make queries like this:

```
var orders = session.Query<Customer>().SelectMany(c => c.Orders).ToArray();
```

I get a proper inner join on my customer. but if I do the same from the other side:

```
var or = session.Query<Order>().Select(c => c.Customer).ToArray();
```

I get a `LEFT JOIN` which can make serious performance drops on large data.

The question is: is there any way to instruct NH to use `INNER JOIN` for all my not nullable reference columns, so I am not forced to use `QueryOver`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a real join

```
var ordersWithCustomers = 
   from o in Session.Query<Order>()
   join c in Session.Query<Customer>() on o.Customer.Id equals c.Id
   select o;

return ordersWithCustomers.ToArray();
```

(interestingly left join has never been supported with LINQ to NH, QueryOver rocks IMHO).

Comment: Well, your query works as expected: gives me
`SELECT  customer1_.Id AS Id1_ ,
        customer1_.FirstName AS FirstName1_ ,
        customer1_.LastName AS LastName1_
FROM    [Order] order0_ ,
        [Customer] customer1_
WHERE   customer1_.Id = order0_.Customer_id`
But I want this behavior everywhere not only in manual queries

Comment: I don't think you can. You can tell NH to eager load a collection in its mapping file, but it will be a left join i think. try it: Map(x => x.EntityType).Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Join();

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a Cascade.All() in the OrderMap : IAutoMappingOverride

Comment: No luck: `SELECT  customer1_.Id AS Id1_ ,
        customer1_.FirstName AS FirstName1_ ,
        customer1_.LastName AS LastName1_
FROM    [Order] order0_
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [Customer] customer1_ ON order0_.Customer_id = customer1_.Id`

Comment: The way of how NH handles the cascades has nothing to do with the used join type.